# Updating mail draft using Domino REST API causes message to appear in Send folder

Tags: rest, email, lotus-domino

I am using the Domino Mail REST API and am able to create a new draft mail which appears in the Drafts folder.

When I update the draft mail it appears in the Sent folder and is no longer visible in the Drafts folder.

This is unexpected. The message was not sent. I have also tried setting the From and To fields to null and the sresult is always the same.

Partial code:
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(message);

```
        // if message has an id then do update
        if (href != null && href.trim().length() > 0) {
            url = createFullQualifiedRequestUrl(href);
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "utf-8"));
            response = this.executeRequest(request, username);

        } else {
            MailboxFolder folder = getFolder("drafts", username);
            url = this.createFullQualifiedRequestUrl(folder.getLink()
                    .getHref());
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "utf-8"));
            response = this.executeRequest(request, username);
        }

        if (response != null) {
            SendMessageResult result = parseResponse(response);
            if(href != null)
                result.setLocation(href);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: The fix is available in the latest release of the extension library.  The full release number is 901v00_12.20150311-1316.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in the REST mail API and Richard is correct about the root cause.  The bug will be fixed in the next release of the [extension library](http://extlib.openntf.org/) (901v00_12).  I can't say exactly when release 12 will be available, but it should be soon.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your problem is being caused by something that is setting the PostedDate item to a non-empty value.

The Sent "folder" is not a folder. It is a view. The same is true for the Drafts "folder". It is also a view.  If you go into Domino Designer and look at the views, you can see their selection formula. You will see that they look something like this

**Sent**

```
SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView))
```

**Drafts**

```
SELECT PostedDate = "" & $MessageType = "" & @IsNotMember("D" : "A"; ExcludeFromView) & ISMAILSTATIONERY != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person"
```

Note that these are taken from a rather old version of the mail template, so what you actually see may be different, but AFAIK the idea has not changed.  Documents appear in Sent if they contain a non-empty PostedDate item and the DeliveredDate item is either empty or missing and they are not marked for exclusion.  Documents appear in Drafts if they do not contain either of those two date items, are not marked for exclusion, are not stationery, and are not Group or Person docs. The one thing that is in common here is the dependence on the PostedDate item.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the `PostedDate` is being set and the 'something' that sets it must be the official Domino REST API for updating drafts....

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API specifically designed for updating drafts. There is only a generic API for updating documents. That API call has some options, one of which is computewithform. You haven't shown us the URL that you are sending with your API request, but if your code isn't setting computewithform=true, then perhaps the default is that it is true. Someone else who is more familiar with the REST API could confirm that, as I'm just guessing. And it's possible that's executing code in the standard Memo form that sets PostedDate or other items referenced in the view selection formulas.